# ORA-00904: "Good": invalid identifier ORA-06512

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

1.getting invalid identifier error while updating row_val variable char value 'Good' into the table
2.while inserting number it's working fine but strings its getting errors
3.

```
declare
    count_temp number;
    csv_data varchar2(1000);
    val varchar2(100);
    row_val varchar2(100);
    sqlcmd varchar2(3000);
    col_name varchar2(100);
    col_data varchar2(100);
begin
    csv_data:='good,son,r,,happy';
    col_data:='varchar2(100)';
    select regexp_count(csv_data, ',') + 1 into count_temp from dual;
    dbms_output.put_line(count_temp);
  sqlcmd := 'create table test(id number GENERATED ALWAYS as IDENTITY(START with 1 INCREMENT by 1))';
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(sqlcmd);
    execute immediate sqlcmd;
    for i in 1..count_temp loop
        col_name:='column_'||''||i;
        
        sqlcmd := 'alter table test add '||col_name||' '||col_data;  
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(sqlcmd);
            execute immediate sqlcmd;


     sqlcmd:='insert into test ('||col_name||') values('||i||')';
    
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(sqlcmd);
      execute immediate sqlcmd;
    sqlcmd:='update test  set '||col_name||'='||i||' where id=1';    
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(sqlcmd);
   execute immediate sqlcmd;
    sqlcmd:='delete from test   where id > 1';    
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(sqlcmd);
      execute immediate sqlcmd;
    end loop;
    for i in 1..count_temp
     loop
        col_name:='column_'||''||i;
        select regexp_substr(csv_data, '(.*?)(,|$)',1,i, NULL, 1) into val from dual;
        row_val:=val;
      --in this update statement getting errors    
        sqlcmd:='update test  set '||col_name||'='||to_char(row_val)||' where id=1';    
       -- DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(sqlcmd);
        execute immediate sqlcmd;
    
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put(val||'  ');
        
     end loop;
    dbms_output.new_line;
end;
/
```

> Error
>
> ORA-00904: "Good": invalid identifier ORA-06512: at line 43
> ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721

I want to insert each word in this 'good,son,r,,happy' string into separate columns in a single row

Comment: Uncomment `-- DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(sqlcmd);` before `execute immediate` and you'll see the wrong statement. But it is better to get rid of concatenation, use `sqlcmd := 'insert into test (' || colname || ') values (:v)'; execute immediate sqlcmd using row_val;`

Comment: Which row is 1721?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String must be enclosed in the single quotes.

So you need to change

```
values('||i||')
```

To

```
values('''||i||''')
```

Same need to be done at other places in your code, if any.

Please note that two single quotes in string is converted to single quote.